# Set focus on input field with jquery in specific table row

Tags: jquery, focus, setfocus

I have following html:

```
<table>
  ....
  <tr>
    ....
  </tr> 
  ....
  <tr id="myid">
     <....>
        <input value="..." />
     </....>
  </tr>
  <tr id="myanotherid">
     <....>
        <input value="..." />
     </....>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I set the focus on this input field in table row "myid" with jquery ? I can't set id on input field, because this html was generated automatically.

Comment: Shouldn't it have a name, too?

Comment: This is my problem, this html is generated automaticaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the table as an anchor and find the input regardless of its value.

```
$('table tr#myid').find('input:first').focus()
```

Comment: `$('table tr#myid')` is unnecessary; `$('#myid')` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the field as-is:

```
$('input[value="abc"]').focus();
```

Or if there's a chance that there will be more than one `input` with that value:

```
$('input[value="abc"]:first').focus();
```

If it's the ID you need to focus on, use that in your selector:

```
$('#myid input:first').focus();
```

[more jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)